# OAuth access Jira with google token?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am using [this npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login) to authenticate through Google to the system.
I have Jira atlassian, that uses Google to authenticate.

**Question**

Is it possible to use the token that I received from Google, and use it to authenticate into Jira's API of that user to gather information from Jira such as grabbing all tasks assigned to me, and such?

Or do I have to make OAuth specify for Jira ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this, that is the point of delegated authentication. 
Google will send you an authentication token when user will logs in. 
I never work with google. I always used keyclock (3 part OAuth provider). But that is a beauty of a spec it should work everywhere the same.

It will be save in the cookie. 
It will have o form of JWT.

You have to attache is token to the request that you send to the jira API.
You can try this with curl first

```
curl -i http://dev.myapp.com/api/jira ... \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Ym9zY236Ym9zY28=afsfdsf...."
```

You can find the token when looking at the network traffic in your browser.

Let me know how it went. And if I can help further. I have a pretty good understanding of the OpenIDconnect and OAuth 2.0 standards.

Comment: I have the token I received from google, but when entering it as auth header it says invalid, but if i put in my actual jira password, it will work

Comment: That suggest to me that token authentication is not enabled in jira.  Second possibility is that you don't have configure this 2 applications in single client (they must have the same client id).